# Why won't Minecraft let me log in with my Mojang account?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I try to login with my Mojang account it says "Login Failed". Why does it do that?

Comment: Is Minecraft listed as one of your games under "My Games" when you login to your Mojang account at http://account.mojang.com?

Comment: Not sure why this is being closed as "too localized," this is not localized at all...

Comment: @Danny I think because it's only this one person having problems, is the (inaccurate) reasoning. Really, this needs closing as NARQ because the user appears to have done a drive-by ask and hasn't provided enough info to make it a real, solvable problem.

Comment: It does that because, clearly, your login failed.

Answer (score 5):

Did you buy a legitimate copy or are you using a cracked version? This is a known issue with cracked copies of Minecraft.

If this is not your problem then there really aren't many other reasons.

1. The login servers could be down.
2. You're typing something wrong, recover your password just in case.

If these aren't the problem, then email Mojang.  Also, check this site for info on if the servers are up: http://xpaw.ru/mcstatus/.

Comment: "issue" for cracked copies.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen quite often, and it ofter works for me to go to minecraft.net while logging in. This may only work with Tekkit, and check your internet connection works.

Answer (score 0):

Remember when you use a Mojang account that you must use your e-mail and not the username you used to use for your account originally when logging in with the client.